# Github action deploying zip file instead of contents in Azure App Service wwwroot folder

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions, .net-4.8

I set up CI deployment for a .Net Framework 4.8 project from GitHub in an Azure App Service. I have created a yml file. Here is the deployment portion:

```
  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: ASP-app
      
      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'MyApi'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
          publish-profile: ---
```

When I check in a file, the action is run in GitHub and my build and deploy processes are successful. In my Azure App Service, my Deployment Center recognizes that the process ended successfully. If I go into my App Service Editor under development tools, I can see that files were uploaded to the wwwroot folder. However, the files do not include a web.config file. They include the .zip package that my yml file generates.

I think that the files deployed to the wwwroot folder need to be the extracted contents of the zip file, not the zip file itself. How can I deploy the contents of the zip file to my wwwroot folder of my Azure App Serivce instead of the zip file itself? Is there a command in the configuration of the app service that I am missing?

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy You can engage the developers via the repo or check previous discussions that might look similar.

Answer (score 2):

I followed below steps to deploy .NET framework web application using GitHub actions:

- Created a .NET 4.8 Framework web application and pushed to GitHub repository.

**Folder Structure:**

[image]

- Created a Windows Azure App Service with .NET 4.8 runtime stack.
- Deploying the web application to Azure using GitHub Actions with below Workflow.

**GitHub Workflow:**

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup MSBuild path
        uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2

      - name: Setup NuGet
        uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v1.0.5

      - name: Restore NuGet packages
        run: nuget restore

      - name: Publish to folder
        run: msbuild /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="\published\"

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: ASP-app
          path: '/published/**'

  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: ASP-app
      
      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: '<Web_App_Name>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_59XXXXXXXXXXXXX0 }}
```

- Deployed the application to Azure Successfully:

[image]

**KUDU site:**

- Go to Azure App Service=>Development Tools=>Advance Tools=>It opens KUDU(SCM) site of your application.
- Navigate to Debug Console=>CMD=>Site=>wwwroot to see the deployed files.
- I can see `Web.config` got deployed.

[image]

- Make sure the **Path Mappings** in `Azure App Service=>Configuration` pointing the deployed application.

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply!  I updated my github action yml to reflect your changes. The app now deploys. However, my app is a web api, not a web app. It looks like it is behaving like a web app. The content that is returning is html. Do you know of a way to deploy as an api?

Comment: You have to follow the same to deploy web api as well. Go to Deployment Center in your Azure web app, select GitHub as source and configure the other fields by selecting your repository. It generates the workflow to deploy your application.

Comment: I'm getting an error with mismatching assemblies. I turned custom errors off and I got the following error when going to a url:         Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=---' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)